# How to show Alert when I encountered API request error in SwiftUI via ViewModel?

Tags: swift, mvvm, error-handling, swiftui, alert

Below is the NewsViewModel. What property should I add in this viewModel to trigger an Alert in its corresponding View? Thanks in advance. [image]

Comment: What kind of alert and on which condition do you want to show alert? Also, please add code instead of a screenshot and add view code as well.

Comment: I want to show something like UIAlertView whenever I try to do an API call but encountered a bad request.

Answer (score 3):

I would create an enum type for this. In your view model, I might add something like:

```
enum Error {
  case noNetwork
  case noNewsFound
  case missingImages

  var alert: Alert {
    switch self {
    // Build SwiftUI.Alert instances for each error case
    }
  }
}
```

I then would add this property to your view model:

```
@Published var error: Error?
```

Lastly, in your view, I would add this:

```
// Your view here
.alert(item: $viewModel.error) { error in 
  error.alert // This returns the computed Alert you added to your Error type
}
```

Then in your view model, you just set the `error` property to the appropriate error, and your view will show the alert.